# How do I echo input value in a php script?

Tags: php

[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4phlF.png)I need to set an input value in a php script

```php
<php
<input value="<?php echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->login; ?>">
?>
```

As you might understand my does not work

Comment: And what isn't working?  What value, if any, is this outputting?  Are there any errors in the PHP logs?  What is in `$_SESSION['logged_user']`?  Did you start the session on that page?  Please elaborate on the problem.

Comment: yes I did but for some reason it displays what s on the photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP syntax is very confused.  While inside of a `<?php ?>` section you're trying to directly write HTML, and trying to open another `<?php ?>` section.

Either get rid of the enclosing section:

```
<input value="<?php echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->login; ?>">
```

Or keep the enclosing section and use PHP code to output:

```
<php
echo '<input value="' . $_SESSION['logged_user']->login . '">';
?>
```

Comment: I highly recommend the first approach over the second approach. It could be shortened even more if you do `value="<?= $_SESSION['logged_user']->login ?>"`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: Agreed, though the example given may be contrived and there may be more code involved which could merit the second approach.  Both are shown just for completeness.